# Want one sample post request url to test my android app

Tags: android, post, http-post, retrofit2

Actually i am trying to test some post requests using retrofit. Can any one provide me a sample post query returning json. Url, on hitting, should return a json response if data successfully has added or some error in case of failure.

Comment: http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/ try this one taken from androidhive.

Comment: the response you get from web apis differs, you need to  mention what type of data you need to POST

Comment: ok suppose i have to post a description string... and in response it should return the data in the string as well showing the successful or not..

Answer (score 0):

try this [posttestserver](https://www.posttestserver.com) . it works perfectly for me

POST whatever you want to post to this url and in response it will give you the status and details

Comment: But how to post the messade using this ur. Can you refer me the url..??

Comment: POST whatever you want to post to this url and in response it will give you the status and details(i guess)